# Create custom sql queries on apache superset

Tags: mysql, apache-superset

I tried to create custom SQL on an apache superset but getting an error. The same query on SQL lab works fine.

`Select * from table_name where column_name = 'value'`

I got this error

The connected database is MariaDB

[image]

Comment: Provide complete query text which causes the error message shown.

Comment: @Akina 
This is the full query
    SELECT * FROM averageQueueTime
WHERE OrganizationId='1.2.246.10.2116752.10.1.1.0';

Comment: The query itself is legal. Try to execute it in CLI and receive complete error message, not the tale about it.

Comment: @Akina This is the error I got from logs 
superset_app             |     _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
superset_app             | MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT *\nFROM averageQueueTime\nWHERE OrganizationId='1.2.246.10.2116752.10.1....' at line 2")

Comment: What is the difference for you between custom SQL and SQL Lab? By default, Apache Superset queries involve the tables directly, if you want to run your own queries, you use SQL Lab to launch your queries and save them as virtual tables, but I don't know where the custom SQL option is in Superset.

Comment: Make sure the single quotes are actually single quotes, and not a fancy unicode character.

Comment: @BetoDealmeida It is a single quote, this query works fine on SQL lab but not in custom sql tab

Comment: @RusiruKanchane so weird! Can you paste the actual query?